# TASM - understanding the position of multiple cards on screen

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I am trying to work on a card game in TASM where clicking a card checks if it can be played and so on. The cards are stored in an array and are printed on the screen in the sprite method. I am having a hard time figuring out how to receive the location of each card so that clicking on a specific card will be directed to the correct index in the array. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is _"the sprite method"_? How exactly are you displaying the cards? And which graphics mode are you in?

Comment: @Michael my method to display cards is by declaring two dimensional arrays. Then I begin reading the array from a certain point on screen, lighting pixels if the current element in the array isn' zero. I am using the
mov ax, 13h
int 10h 
graphic method

Answer (score 0):

For each card that is drawn on the screen will you maintain a record that holds the coordinates of the upperleft corner, the coordinates of the lowerright corner, and the address of the 2-dimensional array that holds the pixel data (eg. *card2*).

When the user clicked the mouse button and you fetched the corresponding position (GetMousePosition function 03h), you simple iterate over this new array to find out if the (X,Y) is within one of the rectangles. If it is, you also have the address of the concerned card. And should you need an actual index, then iterate with an accompanying counter.

```
Cards dw  20, 5, 29, 14, card0
      dw  60,15, 69, 24, card1
      dw 105,80,114, 89, card2

Card0 db 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
      db ...
Card1 db 1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1
      db ...
Card2 db 1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1
      db ...

; CX is X, DX is Y 

  ;;xor ax, ax                       ; Optional Index
  mov bx, OFFSET cards
More:
  cmp cx, [bx]                     ; UpperLeftX
  jb  Outside
  cmp dx, [bx+2]                   ; UpperLeftY
  jb  Outside
  cmp cx, [bx+4]                   ; LowerRightX
  ja  Outside
  cmp dx, [bx+6]                   ; LowerRightY
  jbe Inside
Outside:
  ;;inc ax
  add bx, 10                       ; Size of 1 record
  cmp bx, OFFSET Cards + (3 * 10)  ; End of Cards array
  jb  More
Nowhere:                           ; AX=3
  ...
Inside:                            ; AX=[0,2]
  mov si, [bx+8]
```

Here SI gets the address where the pixel data for the specific card that was clicked on.

---

If it is possible for the cards to overlap each other on screen, then you would maintain a *Cards* array with the records sorted in viewing order. The card on top comes first in the array.